# Difference between sum-product message-passing on a trellis, and sum-product message-passing on an LDPC graph with cycles

Tags: computer-science, complexity-theory, theory

I'm trying to understand the Message Passing: Sum Products and was wondering what the difference between sum-product message-passing on a trellis, and sum-product message-passing on an LDPC graph with cycles.

Comment: Can you specify?

Comment: It's not very easy to specify since our course materials are very fragmented and not easy to understand. One of the questions we got on our exercises before the exam was "Explain the main difference between sum-product message-
passing  on  a  trellis,  and  sum-product  message-passing  on  an  LDPC
graph with cycles."...